# How to get the logged in user's download location (C:\Users\{UserName}\Downloads\)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, application-pool

When I ran the app in VS2010, it correctly downloads the file to `C:\Users\{UserName}\Downloads` folder using the below code.

```
string userDownloadFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\Downloads\\";
```

But when I host the app in IIS, it goes to `C:\Users\.NET 4.0 App Pool\Downloads\`

Yes the app pool is in .NET 4.0 App Pool.

How I can get the logged in user's downloads folder by hosting the app in IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET runs at the server, and anything you do in code-behind refers to the server. When you were testing it locally your machine was acting as the server, which is why you were able to get the files to download to the correct location.

You can't tell the client where to download a file. Access to the client's file system is intentionally restricted for security purposes. Can you imagine the security risks if a website could gain insight about your file system and choose where to download files?